# Инициализация одного пула соединений на разные сервлеты Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, servlet, c3p0, pool

Есть веб-приложение, в котором в файле web.xml определены два сервлета. 
Есть пул соединений c3p0, который, как я понимаю, должен инициализироваться один раз.

НО! Если обратиться к одному сервлету, а потом к другому, то пул будет инициализирован дважды и на каждый сервлет окажется свой пул.

Как это исправить, чтобы пул был общим?

Конфигурация application-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.milli"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Конфигурация сервлета 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:application-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Конфигурация сервлета 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:application-context.xml"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

Описание бинов для application-context:

```
package ru.rusal.mishka.core;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.ValidationMode;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration

public class ContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(
            @Qualifier("systemConfiguration") SystemConfiguration systemConfiguration
    ) throws PropertyVetoException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", systemConfiguration.getDBConfig().getUser());
        props.setProperty("password", systemConfiguration.getDBConfig().getPassword());

        final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DB");
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        dataSource.setProperties(props);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource ds
    ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("MilliService");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(ds);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(PersistenceProvider.class);
        factoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        factoryBean.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ru.milli.app.persistence");
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("eclipselink.weaving", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("eclipselink.allow-zero-id", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory factory
    ) throws PropertyVetoException {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Для сервлетов там обычные rest-сервисы на аннотациях @RestController.

Конфиг web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <!-- Display name -->
    <display-name>mishka</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>ru.milli.CleanupContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webportal</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webportal</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webportal</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/image.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/start.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы создаёте 2 `DispatcherServlet`, и в оба включаете `application-context.xml`. Согласно [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html),

> A web application can define any number of DispatcherServlets. Each servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application context with mappings, handlers, etc.

У каждого `DispatcherServlet` будет свой контекст Spring, а значит, бины для каждого будут создаваться по отдельности. Тег `<import/>` объединяет текущий конфиг с содержимым импортируемого конфига. Получается, в конфиге каждого сервлета будет объявлен свой пул соединений, и при запуске приложения он создастся два раза.

Решить это можно, создав root контекст с бинами, необходимыми всем дочерним контекстам. Делается это при помощи добавления `ContextLoaderListener` в `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/path/to/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Все бины, определённые в root контексте, будут видны в дочерних (web application) контекстах. При этом дочерний контекст может переопределить бин из родительского контекста (объявив свой бин с таким же id), поэтому включать `application-context.xml` в конфиг каждого сервлета при такой конфигурации не нужно.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, получается если я объявляю требуемые бины в корневом контексте, убираю импорт из сервлетов, то они остаются пустыми (именно в моем случае двух rest-сервлетов, когда все необходимое объявлено в аннотациях)? Просто пустые xml-файлы, чтобы означить факт наличия сервлета?

Comment: В принципе, верно. Если я правильно понял ваши намерения, то сервлет `webportal` отдаёт статический контент, так что в его конфигурации можно оставить `<mvc:resources/>`. А вот конфигурация сервлета `rest` на данный момент останется пустой. Но в будущем там могут появиться бины, специфичные именно для этого сервлета.